# Upgrading AutoCAD Broke Python Script

Tags: python, com, autocad, comtypes

I have python scripts which interact with and control AutoCAD documents through `comtypes`, if the AutoCAD application is open.  They work perfectly in **AutoCAD Mechanical 2016**.  We have recently upgraded to **AutoCAD Mechanical 2018** and the wheels have come off the wagon.

The following line, directly after the imports (which I rewrote to include the package name for clarity)

```
app = comtypes.client.GetActiveObject("AutoCAD.Application")
```

...now fails with the error message:

```
COMerror: (-2147467262, 'No such interface supported', (None, None, None, 0, None))
```

This obviously breaks everything-- no COM, no interface.  Clearly something has changed from version to version relating to the com object, but I'm not sure what, or how I can specify the correct object here.

(I will note that I've tested the script in both versions of AutoCAD, both using the same test drawing, and that drawing was actually saved in AutoCAD 2013 format, for non-technical reasons.  So it is unlikely to be anything about the file itself.)

Comment: Did you try to clear comtypes wrappers cache or just to reinstall comtypes package (it will clear the cache during install)?

Comment: @serg I'm not sure what it means to clear the comtypes wrappers cache, can you provide more details?

Comment: I do not worked much with comtypes, so the following information may be incorrect or out-of-date. As I know, comtypes generates some code on-the-fly and cache this code for future work with COM objects of the same type. If the old cache will be used for new COM server after AutoCAD update, it can lead to errors.
The cache will be cleaned on comtypes reinstal.
There is also clear_comtypes_cache.py inside comtypes package, which should clear cache, but I don't found documentation about how to use it and also there is some issues with it: https://github.com/enthought/comtypes/issues/182

Comment: @serg Interesting and potentially useful, although it will take me some time to read up on that and test it.  I'll drop a comment when I've had the chance to do so.